# Ways to know if app was built in PhoneGap only by using it?

Tags: cordova

Previous answers specify it's possible to know if an app was built in PhoneGap by doing all kinds of things regarding examining the source code of the app. Some answers apply for Android only (looking at the .apk), not mentioning other platforms like iPhone . I couldn't find information about how to determine if an app was built using PhoneGap without dealing with the code.

At first I thought the scrollbar is a good indicator since it looks idential to the native browser scrollbar (at least on iPhones). I then noticed built-in native apps like iTunes and AppStore has the same scrollbar.
A possible indicator i found is the ability to select text by tapping and holding until the magnifying glass appears.

Assuming PhoneGap wraps a browser object, I'm looking for a look and behavior of a browser (correct me if i'm wrong).

Is it possible to know if an app was built with PhoneGap **just by using it**? What are good indicators I need to look for?